# Proof verification that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$ (sequence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Using an epsilon-N approach (since this is supposed to be a sequence), we require
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N \hspace{1mm}\text{s.t} \hspace{2mm}n>N \implies |a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$
Now, for $n>0$,
$$|a_n-L|=\left|\frac{n!}{n^n}\right|=\frac{n!}{n^n}<\varepsilon$$

We observe that all of the terms must be smaller than or equal to one by writing the terms out:
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...3\cdot2\cdot1}{n\cdot n \cdot n...n \cdot n \cdot n}<(1^{n-1})\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n} <\varepsilon$$

Thus, choosing $N=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ completes our proof.

Thoughts on my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$...$ smaller than or equal to *"one"* $...$ , I would say.

The proof is otherwise totally fine.

Comment: Most definitely, It was a typo!